# How to go from a runtime type (Type) to a bound type parameter (T)?

Tags: dart

> **tl;dr** -- I'm deserializing objects (e.g., an "`Animal`" instance) without reflection and want to obtain its actual type so that I can construct related objects (e.g., "`Result<Animal>`"). I'm also writing framework code so can't simply cast to a type explicitly. Is there a reasonable way to do this?

I'm dealing with serialization and want to be able to use the resulting type in constructing related objects: e.g., if I'm deserializing into "`Animal`", I want to instantiate a container, e.g., "`Result<Animal>`". In order to do that, I need a type (`T`) rather than a type instance (`Type`).

I've found that I can create a list of statically typed helper classes beforehand (`Helper<Animal>`, `Helper<Person>`, ...), find the right one via "`deserializedAnimal.runtimeType`", then invoke, say, "`buildResult(deserializedAnimal)`". This, being specifically instantiated for `Animal`s, knows that it's dealing with an `Animal` and can explicitly create a `Result<Animal>.`

I've also found a way to do this generically by adding a method to the helper with a generic closure argument. The helper binds the closure's type parameter to the static type before invoking it. As a result, the closure receives an instance that has a matching runtime type and static type -- plus its type parameter is correctly bound and can be used to instantiate other types (e.g., `Result<T>` with `T` bound to `Animal`).

All of this feels a bit convoluted but I'm convinced I need something like this to restore the type parameter after serialization (again, so I can pass the result to a generic and trust that the type parameter is bound to the actual static type rather than, say, `dynamic`).

Does any of this seem wonky? Am I missing something easier?

Example code:

```
class Identifiable<T> {
  Id<T> id;
}

class Id<T> {}

class Person extends Identifiable<Person> {}

class Animal extends Identifiable<Animal> {}

class Resolver<T extends Identifiable> {
  void resolve(dynamic arg, void Function<V extends Identifiable>(dynamic) func) {
    func<T>(arg);
  }
}

final dynamic resolvers = {
  Id<Person>().runtimeType: Resolver<Person>(),
  Id<Animal>().runtimeType: Resolver<Animal>()
};

void reveal<T extends Identifiable>(Id<T> id) {
  print("Static: ${Id<T>().runtimeType}");
  print("Dynamic: ${id.runtimeType}\n");
}

void resolve(dynamic arg, void Function<V extends Identifiable>(dynamic) func) {
  resolvers[arg.runtimeType].resolve(arg, func);
}

main() {
  dynamic lst = [];
  
  lst.add(Id<Person>());
  lst.add(Id<Animal>());
  
  /*
    Static: Id<Identifiable<dynamic>>
    Dynamic: Id<Person>
  */
  reveal(lst[0]);

  /*
    Static: Id<Person>
    Dynamic: Id<Person>
  */
  resolve(lst[0], <V extends Identifiable>(arg){
    reveal<V>(arg);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is the simplest way to go from `Type` object to type variable bound to that type (or any other functionality which depends on the precise type, like a factory function).

There is no way to go directly from `Type` object to a usable type without reflection, because doing that *is* reflection.